# Issue with installing ADT into eclipse -noob warning

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, adt

I'm trying to get started on Android development for my self taught technology class. I followed numerous tutorials, but I always get stuck here:

**I told eclipse to find and install ADT from this url:** 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

**But upon install, it gives me this error:**
 Android Development Tools (16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires plug-in "org.eclipse.core.runtime (3.6.0)", or later version.

I have googled around but I cant seem to find what it really means or how to install or obtain what its asking. I'm completely newto this whole development field, i only have experience in VB.net and I really want to start developing android apps to build a portfolio for my class. Thank you so much, I really appreciate all your time

Comment: Make sure you have downloaded and updated SDK packages before downloading the ADT

Answer (score 2):

That error stats that your eclipse is older version. you need to download or update eclipse for installing Android ADT.

Comment: If it was helpful for you  then please accept the answer so that it can be helpful for others.

Comment: 3.6 = Eclipse Helios. user989805 should consider using Eclipse Indigo however - the content assist (among other things) are buggy in Helios and pretty f-king slow/hangs with Android sometimes.